# How to use SUM window function on a column that requires data conversion (and filtering away non convertible numbers)?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to aggregate a subset of values from `colB` (nvarchar) by filtering out all non-convertible values from this column first. I'm using a CTE along the lines of:

```
;with cte as (
  select
    colA,
    colB
  from Tbl
)

select
  cte.colA,
  sum(convert(int, cte.colB))
from cte
where cte.colA in (...)
group by cte.colA
```

The filtering on `colA` guarantees that all the values in `colB` are convertible to ints. But the aggregation results in an error...

I get this message:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Yes' to data
>   type int.

Without the grouping there is no 'Yes' value in the result set. All of the result set are numbers.

So I guess that the aggregation is happening before the where filter is being applied. How can I get around this?

A link to a gist with the actual query is available here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zachsa/f38b08357ad4841a8e776db9226ef66d/raw/071f17ab0079d370e1aec2b70e1f976dc74fd1ea/Aggregating%2520and%2520filtering

Comment: if you are using SQL Server 2016, you can use `TRY_CONVERT`: `sum(try_convert(int,cte.ColB))`

Comment: See this answer for an explanation of why this happens: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191701/tsql-divide-by-zero-encountered-despite-no-columns-containing-0/5203211#5203211 and the (previously known as connect item): bug report: [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

Comment: Thanks @Lamak. I have to maintain compatibility with SQL Server 2012, but try_convert seams to work on that version as well, and that solved my problem

Comment: Why do you need a CTE when it is just a straight select?

Comment: It is a select now. initially i wrote it with `not in` where clause requiring a re-joining of the initial select - so i would have had to have written the join statements twice. I'm not sure what the difference in terms of execution is

Comment: > Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Yes' to data type int. This kind of error happens when you're trying to convert a non-numerical string, e.g a word, to a number.